# Android ViewBindings across dynamic features

Tags: android, android-viewbinding, dynamic-feature-module

So happenned that I have a  main app module

*build.gradle*

```
    dynamicFeatures = [":myFeature"]

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

*AdroidManifest.xml*

```
package="com.mydomain.testproject"
```

With some common layouts which I'm using across the app
eq: `app/res/error_view.xml`

**And I have the dynamic feature files**

*build.gradle*

```
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

*AdroidManifest.xml*

```
package="com.mydomain.testproject.myFeature"
```

*myfeature_fragment.xml*

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/error_view"
        layout="@layout/error_view"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

*MyFeatureFragment.kt*

```
binding = MyFeatureFragmentBinding.bind(view)
```

and here comes the problem .
When i try to access the `binding.errorView` AS shows an error `Cannot access class 'com.mydomain.testproject.myFeature.databinding.ErrorViewBinding'. Check your module classpath for missing  or conflicting dependencies`

The strange thing is when I check the generated `MyFeatureFragmentBinding` class it contains the following

```
  @NonNull
  public final View errorView;
```

So I guess AS knows more than it shows for me.
Also I found in the main module's generated classes the original `ErrorViewBinding` and OFC it's working flawlessly from there.

Someone managed to reference a common layout from another feature-module ?
or how can I enforce the type of the generated common view binding?

Comment: As a dumb workaround I made some changes,
I wrapped the `errorView` to be a custom view (still in the app module)
and referencing in the layouts as `<com.mydomain.testproject.common.ErrorView..`
instead of the `<include`.
With this the ViewBinding works, but its not the real solution.

Comment: did you find any better solution?

Comment: Nope, at the moment I have to use the workaround with custom views to make it work.

Comment: have you open report in the google issuetracker?

Comment: @Stumi workaround is preferred in our project nows, as we don't want to use Data Binding tho :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem after applying this plugin **inside the dynamic module Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

then inside android block enable data binding like this

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

for who are using gradle.kts files like me

```
plugins {
id("kotlin-kapt")
}
```

and inside android block enable data binding like this

```
// enable data binding inside module
dataBinding.apply {
    isEnabled = true
}
```